# .NET Reflector export controls

Tags: .net, forms, export, designer, reflector

I have an assembly made by myself but I lost the source. That time I obfuscated it but I have de-obfuscated it. But it's full of crap now xD Reflector crashes when i'm trying to view some parts of the code. I tryed exporting the whole assembly into a project but I get error/exceptions.

I came up with a new idea. I'd like to get the whole forms, so just the controls etc...
no even handlers and stuff just the code to re-create the form. So i want an exact (almost exact) copy of the form from my assembly. Usally this is located in the FormName.Designer.cs file but I can't reach that. I can't find it...

Because my idea behind this was:
Re-create the form and then load the old assembly and use it as a reference and link everything up.

EDIT: Sorry my question at final:
How do I just export the controls, the GUI, how do I decompile just that?

Kirk

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: Can you display the form if you link this dll into a project? In that case it may be faster (since all you want is the layout and controls) to just display it in one window then re-roll the UI in your favorite IDE.

Comment: I'am able to do that. I just used the exe as a reference and then opened the dialog. But that's not how I want it. The GUI needs to be heavily re-designed. The code is good but the GUI is ugly and bad.

Answer (score 1):

When you obfuscate code, you're pretty much deciding you don't want anybody to be able to get anything out of it. I'm guessing that whatever you used to obfuscate it also obfuscated the designer classes, etc. Your time will be better spent running the program and trying to recreate the forms by hand than by attempting to pull data from the obfuscated executable.

For future reference, there's a lot to be said for source control. Even just setting up a Mercurial repository in a Dropbox folder is enough to save you a lot of heartache.

Comment: Guess I should've written my comment as an answer :)

Comment: I wrote it about 2 years ago, I wasn't using any source control back then. Since a few months I do and the idea there's a small chance of losing the code is great :) I found out that all the designer stuff is in the form class. Still it's messed up because of the exceptions in the decompiler. I'm going try the download link provided by hibacity.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I'm not offending anyone. But I changed it.

Comment: @Kirk: I understand you didn't mean to offend. It's the word itself that's offensive. Thanks for changing it.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, no problem. I didn't want to start a war :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that some parts are crashing because your obfuscater placed invalid opcodes in unreachable branches of the CIL (i.e. byte code). The result of this is that a JITer will ignore them (because they're in unreachable code) but decompilation tools will blow as they will try to decompile everything including the invalid opcodes. It's basically a booby-trap technique for decompilers.

It may be worth trying to find a tool that can strip the invalid opcodes.

Here's one I found after a little searching, never used it though - good luck!

http://portal.b-at-s.net/download.php?view.439

**Update**

From your comments, it appears that my suspicions were correct, you have bad opcodes in your assembly.

I can't give advice on specific tools, but there are a number of tools to choose from for removing bad opcodes. A Google search found an alternative tool:

https://github.com/Contra/GIOR

Comment: This is a great answer! Even after deobfuscation it crashes at some parts. Gonna try this out!

Comment: Hope it helps you out. If it does remember to upvote and accept answers.

Comment: Well I just downloaded it an followed in the instruction video and if I load my executeable into PEBrowser there are a lot of bad opcodes so it will take a while to fix them all. Now just hope the tool will still run after hex editing lots of times...

Comment: Ok just tryed. I found some bad opcodes and entered the hex values into the tool. It outputs the fixed hex values. Then when i'm trying to find the original hex values in the hex editor they seem to not exist.

Comment: @Kirk I cannot give specific advice on tools, but it sounds like you have got invalid opcodes in your assemblies. I found various tools to remove invalid opcodes after searching.

Comment: Yeah as said there are bad opcodes. The instruction video says to enter hex code into the Bad Op code fixer. It outputs the fixed hex code. Then I need to use a hex editor to change the old hex code (with bad opcodes) to the new hex code (without the bad opcodes) but the hex code that i'm looking for doesn't exists!

Comment: @Kirk Perhaps you should try a different tool. I have updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: Mm it's funny that you give me the github of a guy I daily speak on chat xD Never thought he made such a thing. Many thanks again gonna try it now :)

Comment: @Kirk Hope that helps. Remember to upvote and accept answers that are helpful ;)